# Changing the '?' in get requests using Python on an ASP.NET site

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, get, python-requests

I have been attempting to create a web scraper for the following site using requests and BeautifulSoup to pull the information, after which I will be appending this to an Excel sheet using xlsxwriter:

https://www.calcareers.ca.gov/CalHRPublic/Search/JobSearchResults.aspx#jcid=1&kw=a&classid=540&depid=274&locid=4&postdays=1&tenid=1&timid=1&minsal=2000&appmethid=1&socmajorcode=17-0000

The above link shows each query parameter from the previous page being set to random defaults.

Using requests I am able to deliver a payload with the same link as the above, which I plan to alter using user input once I can get past the `'#'` symbol.

This is the code that I'm currently using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import xlsxwriter

# Argument variables
payload = {
    'jcid': 'value1',
    'kw': 'value2',
    'classid': 'value3',
    'depid': 'value4',
    'locid': 'value5',
    'postdays': 'value6',
    'tenid': 'value7',
    'timid': 'value8',
    'minsal': 'value9',
    'appmethid': 'value10',
    'socmajorcode': 'value11'
}

# Request
r = requests.get(
    'https://www.calcareers.ca.gov/CalHRPublic/Search/JobSearchResults.aspx#', params = payload)

print(r.url)
```

The response that I am getting from the `print(r.url)` is:

```
https://www.calcareers.ca.gov/CalHRPublic/Search/JobSearchResults.aspx?jcid=value1&kw=value2&classid=value3&depid=value4&locid=value5&postdays=value6&tenid=value7&timid=value8&minsal=value9&appmethid=value10&socmajorcode=value11
```

The issue is that the website won't load with a `'?'` and instead needs to be passed `'#'`.

Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this with requests? It seems like this could be circumvented with selenium, but I wanted to give this a go because I've hit a brick wall with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `requests.get()` method for your use.

```py
import requests

class ASPRequest(requests.Request):
    def get(self, url, params, **kwargs):
        qstring = '#'
        for key, value in params.items():
            qstring = qstring+"{}={}&".format(key, value)
        return requests.get(url+qstring)

payload = {
    'jcid': 'value1',
    'kw': 'value2',
    'classid': 'value3',
    'depid': 'value4',
    'locid': 'value5',
    'postdays': 'value6',
    'tenid': 'value7',
    'timid': 'value8',
    'minsal': 'value9',
    'appmethid': 'value10',
    'socmajorcode': 'value11'
}

r = ASPRequest().get(
    url = 'https://www.calcareers.ca.gov/CalHRPublic/Search/JobSearchResults.aspx', params = payload)

print(r.url)
```